# ClickOnce with f# make

Tags: clickonce, f#-fake

I'm currently exploring f# make and i need to deploy a click once deployment.
But how can a do the process? I.e. creating the .deploy file and the manifest?

Shipping it to the ftp shouldn't be much of a problem ... i suppose :D

I think i could just rename the built files, but it would be nicer if i could start the clickonce conversion directly.

My current script:

```
Target "CompileApp" (fun _ ->
!! (appDir + @"\*.csproj")
    |> MSBuildReleaseExt buildDir ["Configuration", "ReleaseTST"] "Build"
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
```

But how can i create the clickonce files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it! ^_^

```
Target "CompileApp" (fun _ ->
!! (appDir + @"\*.csproj")
    |> MSBuildReleaseExt buildDir ["Configuration", "ReleaseTST"; "ApplicationVersion", "3.0.0.0"] "Publish"
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
```